# Remove alpha and special characters from the column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove alpha characters and special characters(,) from the column values. When trying to remove the alpha characters it gives NaN as output .

Input Data :

```
col2
2565.0
23899
876.44
1765.7
3,253.0CA
9876.9B
```

Output Data :

```
    col2
    2565.0
    23899
    876.44
    1765.7
    3253.0
    9876.9
```

Code i have been using:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r"[a-zA-Z]",'')
df['col2']=df['col2'].fillna('').str.replace(',',"").astype(float)
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: A simple sub regex should do the trick.  Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and regex which matches *"not numbers and dot"*

```
df['col2'] = df.col2.replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Output

```
       col2
0   2565.00
1  23899.00
2    876.44
3   1765.70
4   3253.00
5   9876.90
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z,]','', regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
       col2
0   2565.00
1  23899.00
2    876.44
3   1765.70
4   3253.00
5   9876.90
```